# Можно ли включить в браузере js и не перезагружать страницу, чтобы js заработал?

Tags: javascript

Cтраница загружена в браузер с отключенным js. Можно ли включить в браузере js и не перезагружать страницу, чтобы js на странице  заработал?

Comment: Экспериментируй!

Comment: Думаю можно если "подтриггернуть" все скрипты и событие `DOMReady` из консоли только вот *ЗАЧЕМ?*

Comment: За что закрываете? Это ж не опросник!

Answer (score 3):

Да, JS должен заработать сразу после включения, но вот события браузера, которые генерируются в процессе загрузки страницы, увы не сработают. Более того, код, подключенный в тегах `script` так же не выполнится без перезагрузки страницы. А еще, вы никак не сможете программно отследить момент, когда JS был включен в браузере.

Как следствие, я не вижу способа заставить работать подключенный к странице JS код без ее перезагрузки.